# writeConcern warning while using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, loopback4

I am getting the following warning while using the MongoDB with loopback4.
**Top-level use of w, wtimeout, j, and fsync is deprecated. Use writeConcern instead.**
How to solve this.

Node version: v12.18.2
MongoDB version: 4.2

Comment: Imho - the issue is being discussed on github. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/616

Comment: Updating the version to 5.5.0 worked for me.
`"loopback-connector-mongodb": "^5.5.0"`